# how to print query mysql in php like this

Tags: php, mysql, native

I am newbie in php.

I have one table in mysql (example)
id id_pro name 
1   2            budi 
2   1            adi 
3   1            steve 
4   1            jono 
5   2            galang

I would like to print like this
id_pro name 
1             adi, steve, jono 
2             budi, galang

I have made,but look like this. (Please help me) 
id_pro  name 
1            adi 
1            steve 
1            jono 
2            budi 
2            galang

```
<?php 
$a = mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");
mysql_select_db("aa");

$result = mysql_query("select * from member");

echo '<table>
<tr><th>id_pro</th><th>name</th></tr>';

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td> '. $data["id_pro"] .'</td>';
    echo '<td> '. $data["name"] .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$result = array();
$data = array(array("id_pro"=>1,"name"=>"adi"),array("id_pro"=>2,"name"=>"budi"),array("id_pro"=>1,"name"=>"steve"));

foreach($data as $value){
    $result[$value["id_pro"]][] = $value["name"];
}
foreach($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key . "----" . implode("," , $value);
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

or you can change your sql like this :
`select id_pro,group_concat(name) from member group by id_pro;`

Comment: Fwiw, I’d stick with the first option. More scalable and flexible

Comment: Hi @Genuine Thank u very much for your answer. U fix my problem... Big Thanks